# Smith-Normal Form of Matrices over $\mathbb R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I need to put two matrices with entries from the ring $\mathbb R[X] $ into Smith-Normal form. From what I remember, if the final Smith-Normal form matrix of matrix A has non-zero diagonal entries $d_1,d_2,...,d_n$, then the kth fitting ideal, $Fit_k(A)$ is the ideal generated by all $k \times k $ minors of A and is also equal to the ideal $\left(d_1d_2...d_k\right)$

Does this then mean that if I want to find the Smith-Normal form of the matrices, I can just find the element $a_k \in \mathbb R[X] $ such that $Fit_k(A) = (a_k)$ and then $d_k = \frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}$?

Also I believe that since every number has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb R$, then so long as there are two elements from $\mathbb R[X] $ in an ideal then the ideal is equivalent to $(1)$. Is this true because I feel like there should be a counterexample that I am simple missing.

Thank you for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: ...then so long as there are two elements from $R[X]$ in an ideal then the ideal is equivalent to $(1)$. Well, no. Every non-zero ideal has at least two elements. Did you mean something else ...?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I meant something like suppose we have the ideal $(2,X+2)$ in $\mathbb R[X]$. Then since $X+2 - (1/2 + X/2)*2 = 1,$ we have that $(2, X+2) = (1)$

Comment: As soon as an element of $R$ is in the ideal, then the ideal contains $!$ and so is $(1)$.

Comment: By the way I think your earlier bit is right, although "just" calculating these highest common factors may not  be easy. Why not use the usual algorithm to reduce $A-X.I$ to Smith Normal Form? A lot depends on the  matrix, though.

Comment: Just because I have two 4 by 4 matrices with real polynomials and I expect some of the terms to get quite bad, whereas I can show that with just a few k by k minors that the kth fitting ideals are all 1 for k less than 4 in my case.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248764/finding-smith-normal-form-of-matrix-over-mathbbr-x).